# What's the reason for the difference in pronunciation between "dispatch" and "dispatcher"?

Tags: pronunciation

I checked some online dictionary and found that the pronunciations of *p* in *dispatch* and *dispatcher* are a little different. What's the reason or pronunciation rule for this difference?

Comment: Could you link those dictionaries?

Comment: @Thomson: yes, I looked in a few common online dictionaries and found no discrepancy in pronunciation.

Comment: Could this potential stress on the first syllable be American? The OED and Howjsay say all three words should be pronounced with stress on the second syllable.

Comment: Indeed it is American. *American Heritage* and *Merriam-Webster online* both say that for the noun *dispatch* the stress may be on either the first or second syllable (and I pronounce it on the first) but the verb has stress on the second. *Am. Her.* also says that *dispatcher* is stressed on the second.

Comment: The difference is due to the 'er' on the end.  At least, when I say them, that's the only difference.

Comment: @Alenanno, I referred to http://www.iciba.com/dispatcher/ and http://www.iciba.com/dispatch/. It seems both of 2 pronunciation stress on the second syllable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Dispatch* (as a verb) has stress on the second syllable; *dispatcher* has stress on the first. English unvoiced stops [p], [t], and [k] are heavily [aspirated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspiration_%28phonetics%29) at the start of a word, and somewhat in stressed syllables. Consider the difference between the first and second /t/ in *potato*.

I note that you're located in Beijing: consider Standard Mandarin, where there's no difference in [voicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_%28phonetics%29) between 大 *dà* and 他 *tā*, where /d/ = [t] and /t/ = [tʰ].

Comment: Not in my dictionary, it doesn't. The *American Heritage* dictionary says that *dispatch* has the accent on the second syllable when it's a verb and the first when it's a noun. But *dispatcher* has an accent on the second syllable (its root is the verb). In my experience, this word commonly occurs only in the term *taxi dispatcher*, where it definitely has the accent on the second syllable. (I suppose that a *dispatcher* whose job was writing *dispatches* might have the accent on the first syllable.)  I agree that stress is the only reason you might pronounce these 'p's differently

Comment: @Peter Shor: It seems *dispatcher* has primary stress on the first syllable when it's isolated, but more generally on the second. I typically hear it in isolation or, as you mentioned, in context with *dispatch(es)*, so chalk it up to prosody. My point about stress stands, at least.

Comment: I seems a common phenomenon that a two-syllable word that can be either a noun or a verb has the accent on the first syllable as a noun and the second as a verb.  Consider `object` and `subject`.

Comment: +1 for making the connection to Mandarin. This is a very tricky case where the difference in pronunciation is entirely allophonic in English, so all of the English speakers say "there is no difference", while the poor non-native cannot help but perceive the difference that *is* phonemic in his native lang.

Comment: @Jon Purdy, thanks for your answer. I just noticed that you said there is no difference in voicing da and ta in standard Mandarin, but we can observe the different voice between these 2 character, of course. Or I misunderstand the meaning of voicing here?

Comment: @Thomson: There's a difference between "Standard Mandarin" and the way that people *actually* speak Mandarin. In Standard Mandarin, there is no voicing, and the consonants are differentiated only by aspiration.